# Linux Python Azure Function APP - pyodbc module not found despite being in requirements.txt and other modules working fine

Tags: python, azure-functions, pyodbc

I'm using a `Linux consumption` plan.

I get the following error;

`Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'`

I have added `pyodbc` in the `requirements.txt` file and other modules in this file such as azure-storage are working fine.

Has anyone seen this issue or can confirm this is a known bug? I can't see any way to manually install this.

Comment: Have you run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: how do you deploy the site?

Comment: I don't have an ability to run commands as it's a consumption plan which the shell does not work (freezes).

Comment: I deploy using the func command which packages zip and uploads.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this a bug with the Python worker. I have opened an issue with the team as I am having this issue also. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/249