# Azure Linux Function Module not Found pyodbc

Tags: azure-functions, pyodbc

I have a created a local azure linux function and tested succesfully with `func start`. After testing **Azure Devops Pipe Line** promote it to the Azure (Linux) Function. The deployment seems to be in order.

[image]

Looking in the monitoring during the testing of the Azure (Linux) function it returns the following error:

> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'pyodbc'. Troubleshooting Guide:
> https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 305, in _handle__function_load_request func =
> loader.load_function( File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py",
> line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py",
> line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py",
> line 85, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
> level) File "/home/site/wwwroot/get_nji_metadata/**init**.py", line 3,
> in  from .Metadata import MetaData File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/get_nji_metadata/Metadata.py", line 2, in 
> import pyodbc

**Requirements.txt**

```
astroid==2.4.2
azure-functions==1.2.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
idna==2.9
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.5.3
pyodbc==4.0.30
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
toml==0.10.1
urllib3==1.25.9
wrapt==1.12.1
```

**Question**

1. Is there a way to solve this issue in the "Linux variant" . I already looked at the [Linux Python Azure Function APP - pyodbc module not found despite being in requirements.txt and other modules working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428025/linux-python-azure-function-app-pyodbc-module-not-found-despite-being-in-requi) but don't understand the solution of this guy. Also looked at the Microsoft documentation.
2. Do i solve this issue on the "Windows variant" for Azure Functions ?

Please help me?

Manny thanks Erik

Comment: Pyodbc is notoriously annoying to deal with. Can you install other packages on Linux by chance? The problem will be solved by sudo apt installs, not via pip.

Comment: How do i do apt-install with azure function?

Comment: Before running the command `func start` or `func host start`, did you run these both commands `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then installing the libraries inside the virtual environment after activating it `pip install -r requirements.txt` and run the main command `func host start` and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i do apt-install with azure function?

You can do this using a [custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python#create-venv) and execute any commands like `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` using bash, PowerShell and CMD.

Before running the command  `func start` or `func host start`, run these both commands `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then installing the libraries inside the virtual environment after activating it `pip install -r requirements.txt` and run the main command `func host start`.